# BufferedReader SocketException: Connection Reset while inserting Cassandra data

Tags: java, cassandra, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing an application that handles the 'L' part of an ETL process. It's a pretty simple premise: grab some files from a Google Cloud Platform storage bucket (where each file contains data corresponding to one Cassandra table, and each line represents one entry to be inserted to the indicated table) and insert the data into Cassandra.

The biggest file (and the only one currently giving me an issue) is about 900KB (~25k lines, 4 columns, maybe 50 characters). The next biggest file is about 300KB.

The problem is that when attempting to insert the records from the 900KB file the job gets about halfway, maybe a little less, before I get a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`.

Here's the code:

```
*The GCP related stuff*
Storage storage = StorageFactory.getService();
Storage.Objects.Get listRequest = storage.objects().list(bucketName);
List<StorageObject> results = new ArrayList<>();
Objects objects;

do {
   objects = listRequest.execute();
   results.addAll(objects.getItems());
   listRequest.setPageToken(objects.getNextPageToken());
} while (objects.getNextPageToken() != null);

List<Storage.Objects.Get> files = new ArrayList<>();
for (StorageObject storageObject : storageObjects) {
    files.add(storage.objects().get(bucketName, storageObject.getName());
}

*The processing stuff*
for (Storage.Objects.Get file : files) {
    file.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.executeMediaAsInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] columnData = line.trim().split("\\|");
            DomainObject domainObject = convertLineToObject(columnData);
            domainObjectRepository.saveObject(domainObject);
            line = reader.readLine();
         }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         log.error("log stuff" + ex.toString);
     }
```

This code is broken up across a couple different classes. Trying to provide comprehensive code without the extraneous details. The `convertLineToObject` function simply takes the String array, creates a `new DomainObject()` and sets each index in the `columnData` array to the appropriate field.

I'm using an in-house library that creates a DAO provider and handles the database operations.  The `domainObjectRepository.saveDomainObject()` call is just a single line of code invoking that library:

```
domainObjectDAOProvider.getDAO(DomainObject.class).insert(domainObject);
```

The `insert()` call builds a BoundStatement and calls `execute()` on that statement.

Here's the stack trace I'm getting:

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3336)
com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse$SizeValidatingInputStream.read(NetHttpResponse.java:169)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
*The application call - referring to line = reader.readLine()*
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I comment out only the database call it flies through the file in not time flat.  When that call is active, the performance is slower and it throws that exception somewhere between line 8000 and 11000.  I've checked the data in the file and it's fine. No malformed data, no weirdness in there at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the connection open long enough without consuming more data, Google Cloud Storage will terminate the connection as idle. If your database calls are taking too long, cache the input data locally. You could also, presumably, create a wrapper class that produced new `InputStreamReader`s at the last read offset when you get a `SocketException` using [`MediaHttpDownloader.setBytesDownloaded`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/media/MediaHttpDownloader#setBytesDownloaded(long)) on the subsequent calls, but that wastes both client and server resources keeping the connection open for longer than necessary.